# Getting a Pandas Dataframe result file from native xgboost.train()

Tags: python, xgboost

One can get a result file from `xgboost.train()` with the argument `evals_result` as follows:

```py
import xgboost as xgb
import sklearn as sk
from typing import Dict, List, Union, Tuple


def metric_r2(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> Tuple[str, float]:
    """ compute R^2` (coefficient of determination) regression score function"""
    y = dtrain.get_label()
    return "R2", sk.metrics.r2_score(y, predt)


results: Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[List[float], List[Tuple[float, float]]]]] = {}
xgb_model: xgb.Booster = xgb.train(
    params, d_train, num_boost_round=100,
    evals=[(d_train, "train"), (d_test, "test")], verbose_eval=True, custom_metric=metric_r2,
    evals_result=results
)
```

How do I turn this `results` into the following `pandas.Dataframe`:

```
   train-rmse  test-rmse  train-R2 test-R2
0     0.48253   0.480385      0.73    0.72
1     0.35953   0.357756      0.76    0.74
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it works:

```py
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
from typing import Dict, List, Union, Tuple

def metric_r2(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> Tuple[str, float]:
    """ compute R^2` (coefficient of determination) regression score function"""
    y = dtrain.get_label()
    return "R2", sk.metrics.r2_score(y, predt)

def convert_results_to_pandas(results: Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[List[float], List[Tuple[float, float]]]]]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Converts a given results dictionary into a pandas dataframe."""
    df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
    for dataset_name, values1 in results.items():
        for metric_name, values2 in values1.items():
            column_name = dataset_name + "-" + metric_name
            df[column_name] = values2
    return df


results: Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[List[float], List[Tuple[float, float]]]]] = {}
xgb_model: xgb.Booster = xgb.train(
    params, self.d_train, num_boost_round=self.number_of_boosting_rounds,
    evals=[(self.d_train, "train"), (self.d_test, "test")], verbose_eval=True, custom_metric=metric_r2,
    evals_result=results
)
pd_results: pd.DataFrame = convert_results_to_pandas(results)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).